# Before Insert Trigger field not writeable

Tags: apex, trigger, insert

I created this trigger to verify if the Account__r.Number_of_obj__c is null so the user in this case can't insert , but the problem that I get is that the  is field not writeable .

The error is :  field not writeable , how can I solve this ?

```
trigger NewBeforeInsert on obj__c (before insert) {
    
   Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
   Id currentUserProfileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
   String profileName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :currentUserProfileId].Name;
        for(obj__c  newobj : trigger.new) 
       {  
            if ( profileName == 'profil1')
            {
                if(newobj.Account__r.Number_of_obj__c = null ){
                  newobj.addError('Please verify that the fiel are created');

                  }   
            
            }
       
        }
}
```

Comment: one equal sign (`=`) is used for assignment, use two equal signs for comparison `==` in your `if` statement, also, in triggers you don't have access to related object's properties, you need to query them, so `newobj.Account__r.Number_of_obj__c` will always evaluate to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger variables don't contain fields from parent records.

You need to

1. gather lookup values (newobj.Account__c) and put them into Set, either
   2a SOQL current values of Account.Number_of_obj__c and update them, or
   2b create Account records with needed values and DML update them.